# Size of Accumulator Array in Hough Transform

Tags: computer-vision

What is the rule to determine the the size of 2D Accumulator Array in Hough Transform for detecting lines, or in other words,  depending on what factors should we set the value of 'd', and theta?

Comment: what should be the size ... for what? There is no universal value, that can be used to all images and all lines... Maybe you need to read a bit about the hough transform...

Comment: @j.kaspar I've edited my question. This is what I really meant...!!!

Comment: [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2966/how-do-the-rho-and-theta-values-work-in-houghlines/) could help you

Comment: I would also recommend to read the article linked in the answer on the previous link. [this one](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hough.htm)
It provides more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size of array depends on the accuracy you need. Suppose you want the accuracy of angles to be 1 degree, you need 180 columns i.e. theta = 180. For d, the maximum distance possible is the diagonal length of the image. So taking one pixel accuracy, number of rows can be diagonal length of the image.
This is the simple answer I was looking for...